# Possible to refactor hook function in external function/file?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I do like the DRY concept very much. My e2e tests in my nestJS application are using always the same `beforeAll` and `afterAll` hooks - except changing one module.
I would like to put these hooks in another function/file. But doing this I'll loose the context for `app` as far as I tried.

```
describe('AnyModule', () => {
  let app

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
        AnyModule,
        DatabaseModule,
        GraphQLModule.forRoot({
            typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql']
        })
        ]
    }).compile()

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
    await app.init()
  })
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close()
  })

  test('', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
  })
})
```

I thought about something like this:

```
const beforeHook = async (app, Module) => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
        Module,
        DatabaseModule,
        GraphQLModule.forRoot({
            typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql']
        })
        ]
    }).compile()

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
    await app.init()
    return app
}
```

which is called like

```
let app
beforeAll(async () => beforeHook(app, AnyModule))
afterAll(async () => await app.close())

test('', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
})
```

But it returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHttpServer' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are assigning moduleFixture.createNestApplication() to app is just in the scope of the function. Not outside. See here why: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/

But you are already returning app as well. So just change

```
beforeAll(async () => beforeHook(app, AnyModule))
```

to

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  app = await beforeHook(app, AnyModule)
})
```

and it should work fine.